# Link GROUPED BY SUM query with other query (with either JOIN or subquery)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I have the following tables:

```
Payments
payment_id   amount   tax_bill_nr   fk_person_id   payment_type   ...

Person
person_id   name   address   ...

Remission
remission_id   tax_bill_nr   fk_person_id   taxing_year   ...

Remission_State
fk_remission_id   created_on   ...
```

I already have a huge query for the Remissions, which joins all kind of data from other tables. In reality it's over 300 lines long (yes, the database model sucks..), but all the other data is irrelevant for my current issue. The query is currently along the lines of this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT remission_id,
             tax_bill_nr,
             ...,
             row_number() OVER (PARITION BY rr.remission_id ORDER BY rs.created_on) rn
      FROM Remission r
      LEFT JOIN Remission_State rs ON rs.fk_remission_id = r.remission_id
      LEFT JOIN ...
      ORDER BY taxing_year, remission_id
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

I've created a separated query which gets the sum of the Payments, grouped by `tax_bill_nr`. This separated query will also get the `tax_bill_number` and Person data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT temp.tax_bill_nr,
                pers.person_id,
                temp.amount_sum AS total_amount
FROM (SELECT p.tax_bill_number, sum(p.amount) AS amount_sum
      FROM Payments p
      WHERE p.payment_type = 6 -- Remission_Payment
      GROUP BY p.tax_bill_nr) temp
LEFT JOIN Payments p2 ON temp.tax_bill_nr = p2.tax_bill_number
LEFT JOIN Person pers ON pers.person_id = p2.fk_person_id;
```

I basically want to combine the two queries. Or to be more precise, add the `total_amount` to the output of the first query, by linking the Remission and Payments-sum by `tax_bill_nr`.

Due to the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` construction, I'm not sure how to do so, though. I've tried with a subquery, but then I get errors like *missing right parenthesis*, *too many values*, and other cryptic syntax errors (which means something is wrong, but Oracle doesn't know exactly what)..

The queries above are Oracle SQL (and if it's relevant, the Oracle database server uses version 12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use **CTE**(common table expression) for cleaner code as following:

```
-- CTE
WITH AMOUNTS (tax_bill_number, amount_sum)
AS
(SELECT p.tax_bill_number, sum(p.amount) AS amount_sum
      FROM Payments p
      WHERE p.payment_type = 6 -- Remission_Payment
      GROUP BY p.tax_bill_nr)
--
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT remission_id,
             tax_bill_nr,
             ...,
             A.amount_sum, -- THIS IS YOUR REQUIRED DATA
             row_number() OVER (PARITION BY rr.remission_id ORDER BY rs.created_on) rn
      FROM Remission r
      LEFT JOIN Remission_State rs ON rs.fk_remission_id = r.remission_id
      LEFT JOIN ...
      -- ADDED FOLLOWING JOIN 
      LEFT JOIN AMOUNTS A ON (A.tax_bill_number = tax_bill_nr)
      ORDER BY taxing_year, remission_id
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As you have the 2 sets of data as outcome join them with each other based on the common column present in to it.
For e.g.

```
        Query 1 Result
```

Columns--> a, b, c, d

```
        Query 2 Result
```

Columns--> a, b, d, e, sum(f)

```
      Desired result
```

Columns --> a, b, c, d, e, sum(f)

in above scenario columns a and B is common between both the results, then We can write one more inner join query on the output of both queries.

*Select * (query1) as temp1 inner join (query2) as temp2 on temp1.a=temp2.a and temp1.b=temp2.b ;*

In you case column  **tax_bill_nr** is common so you can join the output of both queries based on this column.